# CheckChanged will not fire

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to learn C# and ASP.net, and I'm having trouble figuring out checkbox events.

Phone Class:

```
public CheckBox chkBox { get; set; }

chkBox = new CheckBox();
chkBox.CheckedChanged += chkBox_CheckedChanged;

void chkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
foreach (Phone p in building.Phones)
{
    TableCell cell_switch = new TableCell();
    cell_switch.Controls.Add(p.chkBox);
    row.Cells.Add(cell_switch);
}
```

All of my checkboxes show up in the table with no issues, but when I check a box I cannot get the code to break on the CheckChanged event. I'm sure that I'm misunderstanding something fundamental here, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you add your CheckBox to your `Page`? Also, make sure you setup the event handler during the right moment (ASP.NET page lifecycle)

Comment: I added the Checkboxes to the page in the foreach shown above. Is there some other way to need to add it? My event handler is just sitting in the Phone class, not sure about page lifecycle... Could you elaborate?

Comment: If you want to have dynamic controls invoke events you will need to add them durin Page.Init or Page.PreInit events. Otherwise they are not recognizes by the runtime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the code changes that I made to the Default.aspx.cs

```
    public class Building
    {
        public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
        public Building()
        {
            Phones = new List<Phone>()
            { 
                new Phone(),
                new Phone()
            };
        }
    }

    public class Phone
    {
       public CheckBox chkBox { get; set; }
       public Phone()
       {
           chkBox = new CheckBox();
           chkBox.CheckedChanged += chkBox_CheckedChanged;
           chkBox.AutoPostBack = true;
       }

       void chkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
    }

    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Building building = new Building();
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["phoneCheckboxList"] != null)
            {
                List<CheckBox> phoneCheckboxList = Session["phoneCheckboxList"] as List<CheckBox>;
                BuildTable(phoneCheckboxList);
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<CheckBox> phoneCheckboxList = new List<CheckBox>();
            BuildTable(phoneCheckboxList);
        }

        private void BuildTable(List<CheckBox> phoneCheckboxList)
        {
            foreach (Phone p in building.Phones)
            {
                TableCell cell_switch = new TableCell();
                cell_switch.Controls.Add(p.chkBox);
                row.Cells.Add(cell_switch);
                phoneCheckboxList.Add(p.chkBox);
            }
            if (Session["phoneCheckboxList"] == null)
                Session["phoneCheckboxList"] = phoneCheckboxList;
        }
    }   

And in the Global.asax page add the following code:

        protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext context = base.Context;
            HttpRequest request = context.Request;
            string pageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(request.RawUrl);
            if (pageName != "Default")
            {
                if (context.Session["phoneCheckboxList"] != null)
                    context.Session.Remove("phoneCheckboxList");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am actually loading my table as the result of a button being pressed. When a certain button is pressed, I load the table data and show it on the screen. How can I do this from the PreInit method as it appears that PreInit is before it even gets to the OnClick method?
`protected void btnCheckBuilding_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(() => BuildTable(building)));
 Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();
}`

Comment: I updated my answer to give you a way to do this. This should get you what you want. Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

Add your check boxes in [PreInit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preinit(v=vs.110).aspx) method and set [AutoPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
chkBox.AutoPostBack=true;
```

Comment: When I set that to true I can get the code to break on `if(!IsPostBack)`, but it does not hit `chkBox_CheckedChanged`. Also, as soon as I check a box my entire table disappears, I guess because the page has reloaded and the table is not saved?

Comment: @SQone2 you should add your controls in PreInit method. I updated my answer and add link

Comment: Actually row will be null at this stage(Page_PreInit) of the Page's Event Life Cycle and you will get a NullReferenceException. You need to add the checkboxes in the Page_Init event.